# $Factory Undefined Variable

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I am Using Laravel 5.6, in the ProductFactory I get this error: Undefined variable $factory

```
   <?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        //
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 7):

i fixed that with adding this line:
 `/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */`

```
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factory $factory */
use Faker\Generator;
use App\Customer;

$factory->define(Customer::class, function (Generator $faker) {

    return [ 'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail ];
});
```